# Show badge count for the day in the hover window

Tags: feature-request, badges, reputation-summary

Currently, if you hover over your name, it shows you up to three badges that you've recently earned.

That's nice, but it would be good if it could *also* give you the total count (in the same format as at the top).

(Is there an official name for "the little popup that appears when you hover over your name"? Personal summary perhaps?)

Comment: Inspecting the HTML, the popup has `class="profile-popup"`, so I nominate that as a reasonable name.

Comment: Too localized? lol

Comment: It's called "reputation summary" as far as I can tell. @hims FYI as well. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With due deference, how many people do you think experience the 'problem' of getting more than 3 badges per day? My assumption is "not very many". I'm downvoting not because I think it's a terrible idea, but because I think it's a niche problem that I don't want resources or lines of code being allocated towards.

Comment: I don't know, to be honest. If you have one good answer, that one single answer can earn more than 3 badges in one day. I got lucky and earned 5 for a single answer today, I believe. I suspect when people *do* get lucky like that, they'd like to be able to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds fair enough, but only if it will be consistent with the rest of the details i.e. show daily, weekly and monthly gain: (worth to mention it can be negative, tag badges can be removed)

> [image]